# If a multiclass character has two spellcasting classes how many spells do they get?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

A few related items that I'm a bit confused by:

If a multiclass character has two classes that use the same ability modifier for bonus spells do they get those bonus spells for BOTH classes? (i.e. would a cleric/inquisitor with a Wis of 20 get BOTH 2 extra 1st level Cleric spells AND 2 bonus Inquisitor spells?)

Does a spellcasting multiclass character who gets Orisons from two different lists get to cast the full complement for their class level in each class? i.e. the cleric/inquisitor would get 4 cleric orisons and 4 inquisitor orisons? (I'd assume that a smart player would then "know" only inquisitor orisons not on the Cleric spell list for the most part at least)

In a few cases I've seen spells that say "caster level" while other spells specify a specific class ("inquisitor level") - what is the multiclass character's "caster level" for such a spell? Does it depend which spell list they are casting it from - I assume in most cases the caster levels do not stack? (I think there are some prestige classes that do stack with other classes in some cases...)

Answer (score 15):

In Pathfinder, and all 3e derivatives, "one class has nothing to do with another." Really, "one level has nothing to do with another" either - you add on the extra stuff for that level without much complication.

So yes, if you have two different classes, you get the bonus spells for each class, and get to cast spells chosen separately for each class.  (So yes, with orisons, if you are clever you'd choose different ones).  This is balanced by multiclassing almost always being a suboptimal deal in Pathfinder; they largely eliminated the "multiclass always good" and "dips aplenty" problems of 3.5. And one of the reasons for this since you ask, caster levels from different classes (regardless of arcane or divine) do not stack unless you have a feat or power that specifically and explicitly allows them to. So you could take one level in 4 different divine spellcasting classes and have a stunning number of orisons and level 1 spells, and pretty good saves, but you'd definitely be behind a "real" fourth level character.