# Is a Hunter 2/Cleric 1 a 3rd-level caster?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, caster-level

Can a third level character with two levels in hunter and one level in cleric cast as a third level caster?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to remember that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game and edition you're asking about?

Comment: The first suggestion by @MikeQ seems like it answers this question, but if it doesn't, could this question be edited to explain in greater detail what remains unclear? (No offense to Fering, but, Scott, as a (I assume) newer *Pathfinder* player, you may just be better off skipping to [KRyan's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/130536/8610) to that question!)

Answer (score 3):

## No.

The [rules for magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Caster-Level) have this to say about caster level:

> A spell’s power often depends on its caster level, which for most spellcasting characters **is equal to her class level in the class she’s using to cast the spell**.

Comment: So Hunter and Cleric both being Divine casting doesn't work like the example below with Wizard and Spellsinger Example: A Wizard 9/Spellsinger 2/Rogue 2 is Wizard Class Level 9, Spellsinger Class Level 2, and Rogue class level 2. Her Arcane Caster Level is 11, because Spellsinger adds to her arcane caster level... she casts as an 11th level wizard, but only has 9th level class features from wizard; her two levels of Spellsinger class levels giver her the 2nd level class features. Her Character Level is 13.     Also thanks for helping

Comment: @Scott Hunter and Cleric both lack any ability that advances the casting of other classes, they only advance their own.